# Execute an executable under a dynamically-created AppArmor profile?

Tags: 16.04, server, security, execute-command, apparmor

I've been looking into the possibility of running commands under dynamically created AppArmor profiles on my Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS. I'm looking for something similar to the [macOS sandbox-exec](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sandbox-exec.1.html), except obviously for Linux.

Some initial research showed some promise, from a command called `aa-exec`.

- [Ubuntu Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/aa-exec.8.html)
- [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818990/example-of-how-to-use-apparmors-aa-exec)

However, it appears that the argument to perform this functionality has been removed.

> aa-exec: invalid option -- 'f'

This [newer manual version](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/aa-exec.8.html) page makes no mention of it, and I assume it was removed in this version. Perhaps this feature was moved to another utility?

Is there any way to do this?

I'd like to do this without granting permissions to install new profiles into privileged areas. Solutions involving compiling my own code are welcome.

Comment: The `-f` option was removed when they moved over to C, documented [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2015-December/008985.html_). Something about preventing things from being run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at firejail, which can create a sandbox per application :

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firejail

https://firejail.wordpress.com/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firejail

Comment: Hey, that looks like a good alternative! I'll check it out.